# Why does PHP parse these if/else statements & include/redirect statements in such a way?

Tags: php, class, parsing, redirect, include

If you have a better, more precise title for this, please let me know.

This has to do with the way php parses, or otherwise interprets the order in the following - similar - blocks of code.

I will be very general in my code and very specific in my question.

- I have two Controllers: "Login" and "Members".
- Both of them access the same "Template.php" model and use that template to load a View.
- Template Class stores series of alerts in an Array using $this->setAlert(), that are all displayed in the views using $this->getAlert().
- Since both of the View pages are evoked FROM the Template Class, using $this is fine.
- In fact, everything works... except for a very curious thing...

**Scenario A ("success message" IS displayed when redirecting to Members view)**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if ("check whether fields are empty") {
        "set error"
        $Template->include("v_login.php")
    }

    else if  ("check if username or password are incorrect") {
        "set error"
        $Template->include("v_login.php")
    }

    else {
        "set success message"
        $Template->redirect("v_members.php")
    }
}
```

**Scenario B ("success message" is NOT displayed when redirecting to Members)**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if ("check whether fields are empty") {
        "set error"
    }

    else if  ("check if username or password are incorrect") {
        "set error" 
    }

    else {
        "set success message"
        $Template->redirect("v_members.php")
    }
  $Template->include("v_login.php")
}
```

**My question is:**

1. Why does **Scenario B** not display any alerts in Members, since the "redirect" method should be evoked before the "include" method at the end?
2. Why, if this is a mistake in code (which it is), does the page "v_login.php" not get appended to the bottom of the Members page using include, since it has been evoked after being redirected?
   This is why it took me so long to figure out where in the error lied in the code.

Thank you for your feedback, and for the improvement of ours and of our future generations.

Comment: The danger with PSEUDO Code is you only get PSEUDO Answers

Comment: Without seeing `$Template->redirect`, I can only guess that it's not exiting after the redirect, so it continues on to the include function.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply.

This is the template redirect method:

function redirect($url) {
    header("Location: $url");
  }

and this is include:

  function load($url) {
    include($url);
  }